# Disallow Multi-Line Commenting via Checkstyle

Tags: java, checkstyle

Wondering if there is a particular rule or property that would make Checkstyle (release 6.5+) error out in the presence of multi-line comments as in:

```
/*
 a multi-line comment, could Checkstyle detect them?
*/
public Foo bar() {
    ...
}
```

I believe having a specific Regex pattern rule could be an option but curious about if Checkstyle has already had a dedicated rule/property that could do the trick.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why? do you want to ensure people use javadoc when writing such public api comments? (which would make sense to a certain degree)

Comment: I am just curious, but why do you want to delete multiline comments?

Comment: I doubt Checkstyle has a rule which, in particular, blocks javadoc comments.

Comment: @GhostCat exploring the possibility due to stylistic reasons. To give some more context, you may find this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085364/why-is-style-multiline-comment-bad-in-java) helpful. I think Checkstyle can enforce Javadoc related rules in particular but not sure about the multi-line (or, C-style traditional) comments.

Comment: @GhostCat You can use Javadoc style comments anywhere in the code, so actually this makes no sense ... Would be interesting to learn OP's intentions beyond "stylistic reasons"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear from your question, but I am assuming you want to ban all multi-line comments and not just specific styles of them.

This can be done with [IllegalToken](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#IllegalToken).

```
<module name="IllegalToken">
  <property name="tokens" value="BLOCK_COMMENT_BEGIN"/>
</module>
```

Though it wasn't explicit, if you still want to allow Javadocs, which are just special block comments, you will have to use xpath suppression to allow them and ban the others. See [SuppressionXpathFilter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_filters.html#SuppressionXpathFilter).